# QTcpSocket receiving transfer

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I'm having issues with receiving a transfer.

QTcpSocket->readAll() does not read enough bytes when I'm sending to it. When I send 15k bytes, it reads only some part of it and then does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
QByteArray array;

array = socket->readAll(); //just reads some part, not fully.
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: When is this code executed? When handling the signal `readyRead()` or after `waitForReadyRead()` or something else?

Comment: it's in QTcpSocket's readyRead() slot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably the socket didn't receive all data yet when you call `readAll()`. This is because of TCP communication happens in **small packets** (each having around 1KB of data, depending on a lot of things). These packets make up a stream in which the other end of the communication line writes bytes into. You have to assemble them on the receiving side. How you assemble them has to be defined in a protocol.

To solve this issue, you have to wait for all expected data before assembling it. Sometimes it is not known how much data is expected unless you read it (depending on the protocol).

Let's say you want to implement a protocol which says "everything until a line break is something we call a *message*". Now you want to receive such a *message*. This is done by successively reading and appending to a target buffer (like your `QByteArray`) until there comes a line break. However, there is another thing: When you expect a second *message*, it can be immediately after the first one in the TCP stream, so you just read not only the end of the first message, but also the beginning of the second. Just keep this in mind.

When not dealing with signal slot connection, you can write a synchronous receiver for such newline-separated messages like this:

```
QByteArray array;

while(!array.contains('\n')) {
    socket->waitForReadyRead();
    array += socket->readAll();
}

int bytes = array.indexOf('\n') + 1;     // Find the end of message
QByteArray message = array.left(bytes);  // Cut the message
array = array.mid(bytes);                // Keep the data read too early

processMessage(message);
```

When handling `QTcpSocket::readyRead()`, you can do something similar.

```
void MyClass::socketReadyRead() // connected to QTcpSocket::readyRead() signal
{
    array += socket->readAll();

    if(array.contains('\n')) {
        int bytes = array.indexOf('\n') + 1;     // Find the end of message
        QByteArray message = array.left(bytes);  // Cut the message
        array = array.mid(bytes);                // Keep the data read too early

        processMessage(message);

        socketReadyRead();                       // re-call myself to process more
    }
}
```

---

When you want to read everything sent via one TCP connection (until it gets closed by the peer), you can wait for this event either in a blocking way or process the data in a slot connected to the proper signal: `QTcpSocket::disconnected`.

Blocking:

```
socket->waitForDisconnected();
QByteArray array = socket->readAll();
```

Non-blocking (handling signals using slots):

```
void MyClass::socketReadyRead() // connected to QTcpSocket::readyRead() signal
{
    array += socket->readAll();
    // Do NOT process yet!
}

void MyClass::socketDisconnected() // connected to QTcpSocket::disconnected() signal
{
    processMessage(array);
}
```

Alternative non-blocking solution (essentially the same):

```
// You don't have to connect to QTcpSocket::readyRead() signal in this case

void MyClass::socketDisconnected()
{
    processMessage(socket->readAll());
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't really know how long it will be or whatever it will end with, I'm sending raw binary formats. I know how to do it with Winsock or POSIX sockets but new to qt..

Comment: @OvérFlôwz You *have* to know the length, either in advance or by detecting the end while receiving the data. What binary formats do you transmit? How would you wait for the whole message in POSIX sockets?

Comment: I'm reading block by block with size of 1024 and when it reaches the end, returns 0 or -1, (don't remember right honestly) and then write all the data to disk.
I'm sending just raw data, it's not format or anything else, just raw data, I don't know what it would be.

Comment: The end of *what*? When the TCP connection closes? I'm asking, because TCP streams don't have anything like "end of data", but you can close the whole strem (but then you can't receive more data on the same connection, of course).

Comment: did it in assembly, check if you like. recv_loop:
     invoke recv,[hSock],buffer,1024,0
     cmp eax,0
     jle end_loop
     invoke WriteFile,[file_handle],buffer,eax,wbytes,0
     jmp recv_loop
end_loop:
;done here.

Comment: woohoo, getting even more low level. I'm talking about the *protocol* which is independent of any implementation. You have to *specify* how your clients are talking. I appended a solution if you define the end of the data as *the connection has closed*.

Comment: I don't want to read until it's closed :( look, when I use send() with 15k bytes, it sends 15k bytes. I have to read all the bytes from receiver, until data size will be 0 or less (as I showed example above)

Comment: "until data size will be 0 or less" What does this mean? Until there is no more data coming? How do you know this? Look, when I say I'm now going to send you a couple of mails, then I send you some mails. When do you know there is no more coming? Either I have to tell you how many I'm going to send you in advance (send the size before the data), or per protocol (constant), or I have to send you a special mail telling that "I'm done". There is no other way to tell that I'm done (except closing the connection, but this isn't a good design, as it might also close unintended).

Comment: That's how I wrote using Winsock and works perfectly, without any problems :| tried also with 4gb+ files and downloaded without corrupting it. I honestly don't understand working flow.

Comment: I think it's not well-defined how you did it in the past. You invoke POSIX `recv` and end the receiving procedure as soon as it returns something less or equal 0 (`jle`). But a return value of `-1` means "There's nothing to read (currently!)", and NOT "There's no more data coming (ever)". Imagine the receiver has only a small bandwidth for upload available. The receiver encounters a lot of situations in which it wants to read something, but there is nothing. A few milliseconds later, however, the next packet arrives, but it already canceled the receiving operation!

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I mean. About bandwidth, I'll handle that thing later, I need just how to translate the code I provided here to work in qt :)

Comment: If you configured the socket to be blocking, `recv` doesn't return -1 when nothing is available currently. It rather blocks until it is, and then returns the data. As soon as the connection closes, the method also returns, but with something less or equal 0, so you are done. If this is the case (if your socket is configured to be blocking), you *do* read until the connection closes. As I said before: There's no other way to tell the end of the data sent on the other end.

Comment: So you want to translate code that's wrong, which is implementing a protocol being not well-defined? (Well, the protocol is: There is no protocol. Just send.)

Comment: If I don't have any other choice, yes. Because I don't know how long data will be and how it will end, because it's like random raw data.

Comment: And you are sure you want to keep the connection open after transmission? Or do you want to close it afterwards? Because in this case you can always choose the solution at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I want to keep connection up too.

Comment: I'd also like to wait for some seconds for read, to sure it will wait for next bytes :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22291/discussion-between-over-flowz-and-leemes)

Comment: In this case, your code already implements this buggy protocol. It reads everything available. If it is no more available, stop. But there is more data coming, *in the future*. Sorry, I can't help you with this... Seriously, you have to think about a protocol. Like: First send the length of the data, then the data itself. Then it is well-defined.